# How to display admin grid columns on condition basis

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, grid-layout, custom-grid

Here, I am using layout xml file to render block grid columns, but facing issue to render specific column on condition basis, here I want to show/hide column on basis of user role but not able to do this.

Please help me with this problem, how can I achieve this?

I am sharing my layout xml file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="supplier.order.grid.container">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid" name="supplier.grid" as="grid">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">purchaseOrderGrid</argument>
                    <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection</argument>
                    <argument name="use_ajax" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                    <argument name="default_sort" xsi:type="string">po_id</argument>
                    <argument name="default_dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
                    <argument name="grid_url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/orderGrid"/>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ColumnSet" as="grid.columnSet" name="permission.user.grid.columnSet">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">purchaseOrderGrid</argument>
                        <argument name="rowUrl" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="generatorClass" xsi:type="string">Magento\Backend\Model\Widget\Grid\Row\UrlGenerator</item>
                            <item name="path" xsi:type="string">*/*/edit</item>
                            <item name="extraParamsTemplate" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="po_id" xsi:type="string">getId</item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="po_id">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</argument>
                            <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="string">true</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">po_id</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="po_reference">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Reference</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">po_reference</argument>
                            <argument name="escape" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="po_sup_id">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Supplier</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                            <argument name="options" xsi:type="options" model="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Supplier\Collection"/>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">po_sup_id</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-status</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-status</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="po_manager">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Manager</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                            <argument name="options" xsi:type="options" model="Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Manager"/>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">po_manager</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-status</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-status</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="po_warehouse_id">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Warehouse</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                            <argument name="options" xsi:type="options" model="Vendor\Module\Model\Source\Warehouse"/>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">po_warehouse_id</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-status</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-status</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="po_eta">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ETA</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">date</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">po_eta</argument>
                            <argument name="escape" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="po_status">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                            <argument name="options" xsi:type="options" model="Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Status"/>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">po_status</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-status</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-status</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="po_delivery_progress">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delivery progress</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">number</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">po_delivery_progress</argument>
                            <argument name="escape" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="po_grandtotal">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Grand total</argument>
                            <argument name="renderer" xsi:type="string">\Vendor\Module\Block\Order\Grid\Renderer\Total</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">po_grandtotal</argument>
                            <argument name="escape" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name a-right</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="po_invoice">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Invoices</argument>
                            <argument name="renderer" xsi:type="string">\Vendor\Module\Block\Order\Grid\Renderer\Invoice</argument>
                            <argument name="filter" xsi:type="string">\Vendor\Module\Block\Order\Grid\Filter\Invoice</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">po_id</argument>
                            <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="string">false</argument>
                            <argument name="escape" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name a-right</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="po_type">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Type</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                            <argument name="options" xsi:type="options" model="Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Type"/>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">po_type</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-status</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-status</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="po_shipping_tracking">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tracking #</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">po_shipping_tracking</argument>
                            <argument name="escape" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="po_missing_price">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Missing prices</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                            <argument name="options" xsi:type="options" model="Vendor\Module\Model\Source\YesNo"/>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">po_missing_price</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-status</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-status</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="po_verified">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Verified</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                            <argument name="options" xsi:type="options" model="Vendor\Module\Model\Source\YesNo"/>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">po_verified</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-status</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-status</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Massaction" name="adminhtml.indexer.grid.grid.massaction" as="grid.massaction">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="massaction_id_field" xsi:type="string">po_id</argument>
                        <argument name="form_field_name" xsi:type="string">entity_ids</argument>
                        <argument name="use_select_all" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                        <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="export" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Export</item>
                                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/massExport</item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </block>

        </referenceBlock>
    </body> </page>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your app/code/Test/Testimonial/view/adminhtml/ui_component/testimonial_blog_listing.xml

add in the column tag the class attribute:

```
 <column name="nameofyourcolumn" class="YourVendor\YourModule\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\MyColumn">
```

MyColumn class is:

```
<?php

namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;

class MyColumn extends Column{

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        if(!in_array(1,$authSession->getUser()->getRoles())){
            $data = [];
        }
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory,$components, $data);
    }

}
```

in the $authSession variable you have all information about the authenticated user.
In the if which you can read above, I want that if the authenticated user is not an administrator (1 is the ID of the administrators group for me) don't show the column. To achieve this I put an empty array in $data variable, which contains all data printed in the column, as result I don't see anymore the column.